# How do i work with a designed DataSet with C# in VisualStudio

Tags: c#, dataset

I imported a Table in a Visual Studio DataSet, from my local connected MariaDB on my Server. As Example the Table is "T_Users".

**Problem:**  How can i load the actual Data from the Database into the DataSet and access it in C#?

[The Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3NXy.png)

[My actual code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRGJH.png)

**Desired result:**

`MessageBox.Show(DataSet.T_Users.Rows[1].Email.ToString());`

should print "test@gmail.com"

Comment: You create an instance of the DataSet, create an instance of the table adapter, call Fill on the adapter and pass the DataTable as an argument. There are plenty of examples of there. What do you not understand about what they show?

Comment: Also, you don't use Rows. You index the table directly to get a typed DataRow. That Email property will then be type String, so there would be no point calling ToString.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Have u got a link to a solution or an example Code? I don't know how to get to the Data...

Comment: @jmcilhinney Can u post the Code to read 1 Email, what i have to define ect.

Comment: ds.Tables["T_Users"].Rows[0].Field<string>("Email")

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.